# Transfer variables from one class to another class for table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am trying to transfer variables from one class into a table view class as follows [(excellent code for the table view class)](http://www.codingexplorer.com/getting-started-uitableview-swift/?ynano).
I get the following error in `class SecondViewController`:
`xnyCats = catRet.mainCats()` throws an error `Expected Declaration`

How do I get `class SecondViewController` to inherit `xnyCats` from `class XnYCategories`?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class XnYCategories {

    var catsXny: [String]

    init(catsXny: [String]) {
        self.catsXny = catsXny
    }

    func mainCats() -> [String] {
        var catsXny = ["Sport", "Recreation", "Travel", "Cultural", "Music"]
        return catsXny
    }
}

let catRet = XnYCategories(catsXny: [""])
var xnyCats = [""]
xnyCats = catRet.mainCats()
xnyCats[1]
```

---

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBAction func displayTapped(sender : AnyObject) {

    }

    let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"

    let catRet = XnYCategories(catsXny: [""])
    var xnyCats = [""]
    xnyCats = catRet.mainCats() //throws an error 'Expected Declaration'

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return xnyCats.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = xnyCats[row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        let row = indexPath.row
        println(xnyCats[row] + String(row))
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please use `// Comments` to put comments in your code so it's more readable for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking your code  i find out that you are not able to call the    `mainCats()`function from other class so there are different ways to call a  function
1: Create the class object and call the function for example

```
 class Demo {
    func display() {
       println("Hello")
    }
}
 var d = Demo()
 d.display()
```

2: Declare class function and call it. for example

```
 class Demo {
      class func display() {
        println("Hello")
     }
 }

Demo.display()
```

Now make the following modification in your code and u get the result

```
class XnYCategories {

var catsXny: [String]
init (catsXny: [String]){
    self.catsXny = catsXny
}


class func mainCats() -> [String] {
    var catsXny = ["Sport", "Recreation", "Travel", "Cultural", "Music"]
    return catsXny
}


} 
 let catRet = XnYCategories.mainCats()
    println(catRet)
```

Comment: Thank you - I will try this out shortly.

Comment: the       SecondViewController class I get the  error commented below
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
 
 @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
 
 
 let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"
 var xnyCats = ["Sport", "Recreation", "Travel", "Cultural", "Music"]
 let catRet = XnYCategories.mainCats()
 var xnyCats = catRet
 // The error message - Users/jeremyandrews/Documents/swift/Tuts/XnYCtegories_2/XnYCtegories_2/SecondViewController.swift:21:16: 'SecondViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'catRet'
 - Thanks

Comment: let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"  

let catRet = XnYCategories.mainCats()  

in the second class worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much for a very clear answer - the class function was new to me (still in early learning stage)   so this was a great help and I can take the app another step.